# Is "research" singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

For example, used in a sentence of the form:

> His research on molecular biology and computational genetics is path-breaking...

My own guess is that it refers to *one* body of work, hence singular.

Comment: Singular in the US.  No telling what those crazies in the UK do.

Comment: "research" is singular, researches plural.  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/research_1?q=research  - As to AmE Oald says research is uncountable.

Comment: @fg nu As used here, it's an abstract non-count noun. Like most non-count nouns, it's singular in form.

Answer (score 5):

The noun *research* without final *-es* is singular; that with final *-es*  added is plural:  *research is* but *researches are.*

OED lists both count and mass noun usages for *research.* Often the plural is used in much the same sense as the (singular) mass noun, as in

> The foundation opted to fund Dr. Hughes’s research(es) on neutron stars.

Despite what some of the comments have said, I do not believe that the count or plural usage is foreign to American English—of which I am a native speaker, though possibly tainted by some formative years in England. I routinely hear people speak of a research article or paper as *“a research,”* though I do not use the word thus myself. ([This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207877) addresses that usage.) OED lists an American example of count-noun usage with indefinite article:

> 1889   *Jrnl. Amer. Chem. Soc.* **11** 110   An intimate research into the oxims of benzil.

And the *[American Heritage Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/research)* offers both mass (1) and count (2) definitions of *research* as noun:

> 1. Careful study of a given subject, field, or problem, undertaken to discover facts or principles.
> 2. An act or period of such study: *her researches of medieval parish records.*

Comment: So both (a) His research on molecular biology and computational genetics is path-breaking... and (b) His researches [covering] molecular biology and computational genetics are path-breaking... are available. (a), as OP implies, focuses on the scientist's body of work as a whole, whereas (b) emphasises that there have been different thrusts. // I'd say 'a research', especially unpadded, is extremely rare in the UK. // The linked thread does not really answer the question about the acceptability of  'a research'.

Comment: @Brian, So "*..further research needs to be done..*" or "*..further research need to be done..*"?

Comment: We don't have "researches"! Only research is correct!

Answer (score 2):

Webster's Dictionary describes **research** as both the singular and plural when used as a noun.

**Researches** is listed only as a verb

Comment: AHD 1, Webster's 0